# Google Search Console Rejects a Valid Sitemap with no Explanation

Tags: google-search-console

Google Search Console -> Sitemaps -> "Add a new sitemap"

Enter what appears as a perfectly valid sitemap URL (mine is https://helios-public-assets.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/sitemap.xml), and Google responds with:

[image]

No error, no indication of what is wrong, the sitemap looks valid and fine to me (it loads OK)

Any ideas what is wrong here or is this a GSC bug?

Comment: I tried validating the S3 bucket too but that didn't have any effect. pretty much no matter what I do it says "Please enter a valid path to a sitemap in your site."

Answer (score 3):

The sitemap you submitted is not hosted on your domain.   Instead you are hosting it on a s3 bucket with an AWS domain name URL.  Sitemaps are only allowed to contain URLs for domains you can prove you can control.

The easiest way make your sitemap compliant would be to move it off the s3 bucked and to the same hosting as the rest of your site.  [The original sitemap protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) says that it MUST be that way:

> Note that this means that all URLs listed in the Sitemap must use the same protocol (http, in this example) and reside on the same host as the Sitemap. For instance, if the Sitemap is located at `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml`, it can't include URLs from `http://subdomain.example.com`.

If that isn't possible, [Google now allows cross-domain sitemaps](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2007/10/dealing-with-sitemap-cross-submissions) if you can verify both properties in google search console.   So you could verify the `https://helios-public-assets.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/` prefix property in the same Search Console account where your main site is verified and then you would be allowed to use that sitemap with URLs for your main site.

Comment: I cannot verify this... I added my S3 bucket using the "URL Prefix" method and uploaded the HTML file Google gave me.. it verified OK... however, when I go back to add the sitemap again, it still says "Please enter a valid path to a sitemap in your site."

Comment: You know what it does actually work when I give it my own domain's site map which is at : https://heliosdev.shop/sitemap.xml.gz

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I want a solution that is tolerant of a momentary offline time for my app-- I've always used S3 buckets before it seems strange to me that GSC won't allow it now.

Comment: I've never tried to host cross-domain sitemaps, I've always put them directly under the domain like the sitemap protocol says you have to.   I'm not sure exactly how you'd have to submit it to work with google but my guess is that you'd have to add the sitemap under the property for the s3 bucket.

Comment: As far as downtime goes, it is fine if your sitemaps go offline when your site does.   I haven't heard of any problems with Google failing to re-fetch sitemaps if they are offline briefly.

Comment: it is a specific violation of 12-factor deploy principles--- if I have many dynos (or servers), I shouldn't have to do extra work to keep all of my sitemap.xml files in sync across them. The whole point of scalable 12-factor deploy is that I can delegate the job of updating the XML to a cron task and not have to worry about my different dynos being in sync

Comment: this has been the standard way to build sitemaps (using remote S3 buckets) for Rails apps for about 15 years......   https://simonsomlai.com/en/how-to-create-an-automatic-sitemap-for-your-rails-app-on-heroku

Comment: the 'downtime' is a less major concern that the 12-factor deploy, which makes it specifically impossible for me to write the sitemap to the disk, hence the elegance of uploading it to a remote bucket https://12factor.net/